# luakit + awesome wm: make youtube fullscreen work

Tags: browser, awesome

I'm running Arch Linux on my box. I use the awesome window manager, which is a tiling WM, but allows floating windows too.

The [ArchWiki's *Awesome* entry](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Awesome) tells me to put the following in my awesome `rc.lua` to make youtube's fullscreen floating by default:

```
{ rule = { instance = "plugin-container" },
  properties = { floating = true } },
```

Yet this doesn't seem to be working. I've tried the rule they suggested for the `chromium` browser and this worked, which is leading me too believe that the approach is correct.

I'm guessing that the `"plugin-container"` is not the correct specifier for the browser I'm am using: [`luakit`](http://mason-larobina.github.com/luakit/).

So here's the question: what is the correct `instance` specifier to make `luakit` youtube videos be recognized by the `awesome` rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit tricky:

You're right `"plugin-container"` looks quite like firefox.

Unfortunately you cannot distinguish the newly spawned yt-client by `"instance"` since it's simply an empty string, which matches more clients than you want.

I have found another way:
The `"class"` property of that client is `"Luakit"` instead of `"luakit"` for normal luakit-clients.
So a corresponding rule could look like this:

```
{ rule = { class = "Luakit" },
   properties = { floating = true } },
```

But that distinction seems likely to be changed in the future.

You could find out more about the properties of the clients by adding the following code to your `rc.lua`

```
mytimer=timer{timeout=2}
mytimer:add_signal("timeout",
        function () for i,c in ipairs(client.get(mouse.screen)) do
                        if c:tags()[mouse.screen]== awful.tag.selected(mouse.screen) then
                                naughty.notify({title=c.class,text=c.role})
                                naughty.notify({title=c.class,text=c.instance})
                                end
                    end
        end)
mytimer:start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Awesome 3.5, `add_signal()` function has been deprecated and replaced by the `connect_signal()` function (see [Awesome 3.4 to 3.5 - Signals](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Awesome_3.4_to_3.5#Signals)).

This slight modification to @Tyrannodogg's code will work :

```
mytimer=timer{timeout=2}
mytimer:connect_signal("timeout",
    function () for i,c in ipairs(client.get(mouse.screen)) do
        if c:tags()[mouse.screen] == awful.tag.selected(mouse.screen) then
            naughty.notify({title=c.class,text=c.role})
            naughty.notify({title=c.class,text=c.instance})
        end
    end
end)
mytimer:start()
```