# How to keep YouTube video fullscreen after moving mouse to other screen in Awesome WM?

Tags: window-manager, video, awesome, fullscreen

I've managed to get YouTube Flash videos fullscreen by using [two](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58730/awesome-youtube) [tips](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42750/luakit-awesome-wm-make-youtube-fullscreen-work), but whenever I move the mouse pointer to a different screen (thereby changing the application focus) the fullscreen mode is canceled. **Is there some way to ensure that only application focus changes *on the same screen* cancels the fullscreen mode?**

Comment: No as this is a security feature of flash - see http://superuser.com/questions/16055/how-can-i-stop-flash-from-leaving-full-screen-mode-when-it-loses-focus-due-to-a for a possible workaround

Comment: In the last few days, this appears to have stopped happening (disclaimer: I use dwm, not awesome). I use Flash 11.7.700.203 through Pepper. I just hope that it stays this way -- please let me know if the latest unstable version works for you.

Answer (score 5):

Adding the following rule to your `rc.lua` config file (in `~/.config/awesome/`)  should fix the problem:

```
{ rule = { instance = "plugin-container" },
  properties = { floating = true,
                 focus = yes } },
```

It keeps the focus on the flash plugin, so the full screen mode is never canceled (until you press <kbd>Esc</kbd>).

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: Also use: http://christianiversen.dk/2013/07/flash-is-terrible-how-to-fix-fullscreen-flash/

Comment: Great, works for me with `sudo sed -i -re s/_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW/XNET_ACTIVE_WINDOW/ $(locate libflashplayer.so)`, derived from the link by @ehuang. Replace `$(locate libflashplayer.so)` by the location of your libflashplayer.so if you don't have locate installed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solution to the flash problem, but here's a workaround. The following snippet maps to `mod-v` and starts the highlighted URL (the X PRIMARY selection) in VLC.

```
globalkeys = awful.util.table.join(globalkeys,
  awful.key({ modkey }, "v",
    function ()
      awful.util.spawn_with_shell('vlc $(xclip -o)')
    end),
)
```

This method can be combined with the `cclive` tool, which downloads videos from popular sites (also works by highlighting the URL0 and plays them back in VLC or a player of choice.

Comment: How is this a workaround?

Comment: @g33kz0r It's a workaround since it solves half of the problem: After focusing a different application on the other screen the video is still playing fullscreen.

Comment: @l0b0 That's how VLC works and I like it that way. You press `f` to enter fullscreen and `f` again to exit fullscreen. Why should it leave fullscreen just because I focus another application? It could be an option, though.

Comment: But this only applies to direct links to videos, right?  I thought this question was about videos embedded in browsers a la YouTube?

Comment: @g33kz0r Did you try to open VLC, press `ctrl-n` and paste a YouTube URL? That's exactly what this snippet does. (The old version before the edit even skipped the copy-paste step and opened the current video in VLC immediately.)

Comment: Great, didn't know VLC could do that trick.  However, I don't see how a YouTube-only fix is a "workaround".  There are plenty of other sites on the net that use flash videos and do not succumb to this method.  An example near and dear to my heart:  http://www.ncaa.com/march-madness-live/

Comment: @g33kz0r First: The question particularly asked about *YouTube* videos, not flash in general. Second: That's why I added the `cclive` suggestion since it grabs videos from *other popular sites* and it's not restricted to YouTube.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm looking for a general solution.  Maybe OP should add the "youtube" tag.

Comment: @g33kz0r There is no solution, I'm afraid. Adobe first has to accept that it's a bug (which they will not) and secondly fix flash and make the behaviour configurable (which they will not).

Comment: Here is something interesting:  http://deve.loping.net/projects/ignoflash/  Have you seen it?