# How to escape text in awful.util.spawn_with_shell command?

Tags: escape-characters, awesome

Based on a [suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68158/3645), I've now got the following call in [rc.lua](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/924487c49921e4eb8dd700984b935b2fe1763888/.config/awesome/rc.lua#L309):

```
awful.util.spawn_with_shell('vlc $(xclip -o)')
```

How do I ensure that the output of `xclip` is escaped so that *space characters* are not taken as parameter separators? For example, if I select the string "foo bar" (without the quotes) and press <kbd>Mod4</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> VLC complains about being unable to open *both* "foo" *and* "bar".

To illustrate, in a shell context I would validate the issue as follows:

```
$ params() {
    for param
    do
        echo "$param"
    done
}
$ params $(xclip -o)
params
$(xclip
-o)
```

And fix it like this:

```
$ params "$(xclip -o)"
params "$(xclip -o)"
```

However, if I change the Lua call to this, it does nothing:

```
awful.util.spawn_with_shell('vlc "$(xclip -o)"')
```

Comment: Either pipe the `xclip` output through `sed` and escape the “unsafe” letters manually or write a small python script and use one of the shell escaping libraries.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need as the output of xclip will not be evaluated by the shell again; The shell will execute vlc and sets the parameter to the value of `xclip -o` without evaluating the output.

To test it yourself you can run things like:

```
echo $(echo '`ls`')
echo $(echo '$PATH')
echo $(echo '$(echo foobar)')
```

Comment: You're right. I've amended the question to only ask about space characters, since whitespace expansion is still an issue.

Comment: @l0b0 this is another issue and it is an awesome problem, see http://www.mail-archive.com/awesome-devel@naquadah.org/msg07931.html - just write a script and call the script

Answer (score 0):

Always put variable substitutions and command substitutions in double quotes. This suppresses word splitting and globbing on the result of the substitution. This should work:

```
awful.util.spawn_with_shell('vlc -- "$(xclip -o)"')
```

I can't explain why it does nothing, there may be some subtlety of Lua that escapes me. As a workaround, you could write a one-liner script

```
#!/bin/sh
vlc -- "$(xclip -o)"
```

and call that script from Awesome.