# How to resume YouTube videos in VLC?

Tags: vlc

Whenever I pause a YouTube video which is playing in VLC for a few minutes and resume it, it simply plays a few seconds (presumably until the end of some cache) and then stops playback. Is there some way to get it to resume the connection to YouTube and continue playing/downloading?

Comment: That's why I use `cclive`! :P

Comment: @Marco This works fine in Chromium (and used to work in Firefox until Flash started crashing), and `cclive` is a completely different use case. I'm using `vlc` to work around [fullscreen issues](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68156/how-to-keep-youtube-video-fullscreen-after-moving-mouse-to-other-screen-in-aweso), and I don't want to wait for the entire 1080p video to be downloaded before starting to watch.

Comment: Using [`smtube`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/smplayer/files/SMTube/) and not regretting it here

Comment: Still happens with `vlc 2.2.1`

Comment: don't pause it. rewind instead.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be fixed in *VLC 2.2.3*. Changelog states

> - Fix resume where you left off

You can find much more info in https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc-branch/NEWS or https://www.videolan.org/vlc/releases/2.2.3.html